# Adding a new line/break tag in XML

Tags: xml

I have been trying to add a new line/break to code within XML and have been unsuccessful.

I have tried so far:

```
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br&gt; 
&#xA;
```

Here is a sample of the code I am working with. I included "`&#xA;`" to show where the break is located within the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dummy.xsl"?>
  <item>
     <summary>Tootsie roll tiramisu macaroon wafer carrot cake.       
               &#xA; Danish topping sugar plum tart bonbon caramels cake.
     </summary>
  </item>
```

Comment: just type `\n` - works for me

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The solution to this question is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dummy.xsl"?>
  <item>
     <summary>
        <![CDATA[Tootsie roll tiramisu macaroon wafer carrot cake. <br />      
                 Danish topping sugar plum tart bonbon caramels cake.]]>
     </summary>
  </item>
```

by adding the  `<br />` inside the the `<![CDATA]]>` this allows the line to break, thus creating a new line!

Comment: `<br />` is HTML, not XML!

Comment: @Peter Really? At least do some research before yelling out things you think are wrong. This is the entire point of why `<![CDATA]]>` is being used.

Comment: Yes, `<br />` is not XML. The poster did not specify that she wanted to receive HTML. As the other answers suggest, a newline in XML is `&#x13&#x10;`. That is exactly the reason why you need to add the `<![CDATA]]>` section, because the content is not XML...

Comment: @Peter CRLF? What about Linux or MacOSX? Still the same?

Comment: @Ruslan, you're correct, CRLF is for Windows. And I was totally wrong about `&#x13&X10`

Comment: I used <![CDATA]]> without line break <br/> and it works just perfectly!

Answer (score 107):

New Line XML

with XML

1. *Carriage return*: `&#xD;`
2. *Line feed*: `&#xA;`

or try like @dj_segfault proposed (see his answer) with CDATA;

```
 <![CDATA[Tootsie roll tiramisu macaroon wafer carrot cake.                       
            Danish topping sugar plum tart bonbon caramels cake.]]>
```

Comment: Err, what would happen if the text contained the character sequence `]]>`?

Comment: You missed the semicolon on the end of &#xD;

Comment: Future reference to myself: for AS3, the above is the answer you are looking for..!

Comment: @deed02392 you should escape either of the ] ] > characters

Comment: @deed02392 See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860902/822870) how to have `]]>` inside CDATA. In short, use: `]]]]><![CDATA[>`

Comment: You can also use decimal values `&#10;`

Answer (score 44):

You don't need anything fancy: the following contains a new line (two, actually):

```
<summary>Tootsie roll tiramisu macaroon wafer carrot cake.       
         Danish topping sugar plum tart bonbon caramels cake.
</summary>
```

The question is, why isn't this newline having the desired effect: and that's a question about what the recipient of the XML is actually doing with it. For example, if the recipient is translating it to HTML and the HTML is being displayed in the browser, then the newline will be converted to a space by the browser. You need to tell us something about the processing pipeline.

Answer (score 15):

You are probably using Windows, so new line is `CR + LF` (carriage return + line feed). So solution would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dummy.xsl"?>
  <item>
     <summary>Tootsie roll tiramisu macaroon wafer carrot cake.&#13;&#10;Danish topping sugar plum tart bonbon caramels cake.
     </summary>
  </item>
```

For Linux there is only `LF` and for Mac OS only `CR`.

In question there showed Linux way.

Comment: Correct I was using a windows however the carriage return didn't seem to work for me. I provided the solution to my conflict above

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but Mac OS X uses LF just like the rest of the unix compatible systems?

Comment: @Peter Mac OS X uses LF, but version 9 and earlier used CR.

Comment: @KenGregory sure but version 9 is Mac OS and not Mac OS X...

Comment: @Peter which brings us back to ST3's original comment, which references Mac OS.

Comment: @KenGregory oh now i understand your comment, seems like i was to hasty sorry.

Comment: Doesn't the x after the # mean that the number is in Hexadecimal, in which case it would be &#xD;&#xA;

Comment: @MartinBrown yes, you are right, fixed post.

Answer (score 10):

This solution worked to me:

```
<summary>Tootsie roll tiramisu macaroon wafer carrot cake. &#xD;Danish topping sugar plum tart bonbon caramels cake.</summary>
```

You will have the text in two lines.

This worked to me using the XmlReader.Read method.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to put it in a [CDATA block](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) to preserve whitespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dummy.xsl"?>   
   <item>      
      <summary>
         <![CDATA[Tootsie roll tiramisu macaroon wafer carrot cake.                       
            Danish topping sugar plum tart bonbon caramels cake.]]>
      </summary>   
   </item>
```

Comment: Gave your example a try but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to give a line break is to do the following :
1> Add the following in CSS - `e{display:block}`
2> Now wherever you want to give a line break, type -

```
<e></e>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using CDATA, try

```
<xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
```

Note the double and single quotes.

That is particularly useful if you are not creating xml
aka text. `<xsl:output method="text" />`

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add my solution:

`&lt; br/ &gt;`

which is basically the same as was suggested above 
In my case I had to use `&lt` for < and `&gt` for >
Simply putting `<br />` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The Way to do Line Break in XML is to use `&#xA;`

It worked for me in Eclipse IDE , when I was designing my XML layout & was using TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Had same  issue when I  had  to develop a fixed  length field  format.

Usually  we  do not  use  line separator for binary files
but For  some reason our  customer wished  to add a line break  as  separator  between  records.  They set

< record_delimiter value="\n"/ >

but this  didn't  work as records  got two additional characters: 
< record1 > \n < record2 > \n.... and so on.

Did  following change  and it  just  worked.

< record_delimiter value="\n"/>  =>     < record_delimiter value="&#xA;"/ >

After unmarshaling Java  interprets  
 as  new line character.

Answer (score -1):

just simply press enter it make a break

```
<![CDATA[this is
my text.]]>
```

Answer (score -3):

This can be addressed simple by CSS attribute:

***XML:***
`<label name="pageTac"> Hello how are you doing?
 Thank you I'm Good</label>`

***CSS***

```
.pageText{
white-space:pre !important; // this wraps the xml text.}
```

***HTML / XSL***

```
<tr>
        <td class="pageText"><xsl:value-of select="$Dictionary/infolabels/label[@name='pageTac']" />
            </td></tr>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
(Using system.IO)
```

You can simply use `\n` for newline and `\t` in front of the string to indent it.

For example in `c#`:

```
public string theXML() {
    string xml = "";
    xml += "<Scene>\n";
    xml += "\t<Character>\n";


    xml += "\t</Character>\n";
    xml += "</Scene>\n";
    return xml;
}
```

This will result in the output: 
http://prntscr.com/96dfqc

Comment: That is a C# example, not XML.