# Line Break in a Label

Tags: html, xml, formatting

Hi I have an xml question and wish to place a line break in the question text, nothing has worked so far. I have tried `\n` `<br> <br/>` and various `&####` I am kinda stuck now can anyone help

```
<tr valign="top">
<td colspan="6" class="tbl_cell">
<question text="Other relevant information: (Known allergies, risks and alerts)max 800 characters" id="admin_other_data" type="textArea" spellCheck="true" maxlength="800"/>
<!--<question text="Other Patient Data" id="admin_other_data" type="textArea"/>-->
</td>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a new line/break tag in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917555/adding-a-new-line-break-tag-in-xml)