# How to add a new line in MS excel header text generated using jrxml

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I have a jrxml file using which excel sheet is generated. The line from jrxml is shown below:

```
<text><![CDATA[Historical Places]]></text>
```

In my excel sheet I want Historical and Places to be displayed in two different lines. I tried some things from the link which was meant for xml
[Adding a new line/break tag in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917555/adding-a-new-line-break-tag-in-xml) and it didn't work.

These are some of the ways that I tried but it didn't work:

```
 <text><![CDATA[Historical
                Places]]></text>
 <text><![CDATA[Historical \n Places]]></text>
 <text><![CDATA[Historical \r\n Places]]></text>
 <text><![CDATA[Historical "\r\n" Places]]></text>
 <text><![CDATA[Historical &#x13&#x10; Places]]></text>
 <text><![CDATA[Historical<br /> Places]]></text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I fixed the issue. 
I added splitType="Stretch" and increased height from 29 to 37 in jrxml file.

```
<band height="37" splitType="Stretch">
```

Also made the following changes in reportElement x,y,width parameters in jrxml file. Initially x was 1040 and width was 80.

```
<reportElement mode="Transparent" x="980" y="12" width="100">
```

This fixed the issue. No changes is required in

```
<text><![CDATA[Historical Places]]></text>
```