# Can't YAML::load an YAML:dumped XML value

Tags: ruby, yaml

When trying to YAML::load a value produced by YAML::dump I get an error "did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1"

The YAML::dump value was written to an XML file as:

```
<format_store>---:text_formatting: '':url_pattern: ''</format_store>
```

If I look into the database, it is a text field with line breaks in it.

```
---
:text_formatting: ''
:url_pattern: ''
```

So it looks like the conversion from YAML::dump into the XML format dropped the line breaks.
I explicitly use the YAML::dump format for text fields. XML does not allow line breaks in element values. It would have to be escaped in some way and I assumed YAML would take care of that.

Is there a better way to dump/load text fields or is there someting I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Wrap the YAML content in a `<![CDATA]]>` as suggested in [Adding a new line/break tag in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917555/adding-a-new-line-break-tag-in-xml/17970009#17970009).

Option 2: Configure your YAML library to dump mappings using [flow style](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2544175) (e.g `{':text_formatting' : '', ':url_pattern' : ''`). The exact method for accomplishing this will depend on the YAML library you are using and may require a bit of custom coding.