# Why is my Label ignoring new lines ("\n") coming from the App.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I have an App.config file setup something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Description" value="My too long of a\n description that needs\n new lines so the entire\n thing can be seen."/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Now, at run-time, I need to change the `Text` property of a `Label` to one of these many descriptions located in the App.config file. If I include the new line character in the App.config, the `Label` seems to ignore that it is a new line character and instead prints it out literally. However, if I were to remove these new line characters and insert them at run-time, then the `Label` will recognize them and insert new lines as it should.

My question is, why? Why does the `Label` ignore them and print them out literally if they come from the App.config?

To use this description from the App.config, this is all I'm doing:

```
myLabel.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Description"];
```

Comment: `\n` denotes `\xa\xd` as string literal in C#, but in that xaml it is still just 2 characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a new line/break tag in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917555/adding-a-new-line-break-tag-in-xml)

Comment: You are right, it is a duplicate. Thanks for pointing it out to me! @Sinatr

Comment: This is a question about App.config, not just XML. I would argue against closing it as a duplicate @Sinatr

Comment: @Joe, well, duplicate is language agnostic question and [one of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10918223/1997232) there is exactly what you suggest. And then I thought about `string.Replace`...

Comment: The duplicate question wasn't Windows-specific (although the answer was).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect `\r\n` (return, newline) on a Windows system, not just newline. In any case, App.config is XML, so you want the XML escape sequences:

```
&#xD;&#xA;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep `"\n"` in xml (for clarity?), then an easy fix:

```
myLabel.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Description"].Replace("\\n","\xa\xd");
```