# Does CRLF at end of file count as newline?

Tags: xml, git, github

I'm getting a warning of "No newline at end of file" on GitHub.

If my file has a CRLF at end of file, does that count as newline? Also how do I add a newline at end of an XML file?

Comment: No CRLF just terminates the line it is located on. A new line at the end of the file would be another empty line after that.

Comment: @CoryKramer So just inserting a blank line at the end, dismiss that warning?

Comment: Github complains when the last line does not end with a newline character.

Comment: Yup exactly right

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. @CoryKramer

Answer (score 0):

"No new line at end of file" indicates that you do not have a newline (usually '\n', aka CR or CRLF) at the end of file.

You refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10918223/6216410) for adding a newline at the end of the XML file.