# How to add a line break in the content of XML used for C# .Net documentation

Tags: c#, xml

I need to add a line break in the content of XML used for C# .Net documentation,

```
<summary>
    <example>
        <para> content (wants to add a line break here)</para>
        <code> content </code>
    </example>
</summary>
```

How can I add it?
BTW, < para /> not works for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "para not works for me"? are you looking for [`<param>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/param)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CDATA`:

```
 <summary>
        <example>
            <para> <![CDATA[content (wants to add a line break here)&lt; br/ &gt;]]></para>
            <code> content </code>
        </example>
    </summary>
```

Take a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917555/adding-a-new-line-break-tag-in-xml)

Comment: I just  tired this solution, but "&lt; br/ &gt" will be printed on the screen and seems to be handled as a string.

Comment: Look at the discussion I attached, it will assist you more