# How to create a "Line Feed (LF)" in a XML and XSL files

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I searched Stack Overflow and found info on how to create a "Line Feed (LF)" on XML and XSL files but the info found did not work on my Windows 10 PC... When I view a XML and XSL files all the data prints on one line before it wraps to the next line...
How do I create LFs on XML and XSL files???
Or is this done by: CSS or converting the XML and XSL to HTML???

Your web site will not accept any code!  Even if it is copied and pasted from examples on your web site.  All I get is indenting errors!

[Adding a new line/break tag in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917555/adding-a-new-line-break-tag-in-xml#10923392)

How do I get your examples from the link above to give me a line feed when opening your examples in Internet Explorer or FireFox?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. P.S The line break in Windows is CRLF - perhaps that's why you don't see LF working as you expect.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.
All within the question, no images.

Comment: So which tool do you use to "view" XML and XSL files? Is that question about editing them or about viewing the result of an XSLT stylesheet applied to an XML? How do you run the transformation, how do you look at the result?

Comment: If the duplicate link doesn't help, [edit] your question, explain your problem more thoroughly, and be sure to include a [mcve].